# Joining back a splitted variable

Tags: powershell

```
$(((Get-ADRootDSE).defaultNamingContext).Split(",DC="))
```

This gives the following output. (Literal output)

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $((Get-ADRootDSE).defaultNamingContext).Split(",DC=")



contoso



com
```

I would like to get `contoso.com` as result. Splitting the variable wasn't an issue. However, how would I join the two parts together again? I've found examples on how to join and split, but not on how to 'rejoin' after the split method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`-join` operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847757.aspx) to join strings:

```
PS> "a,s,d,f".Split(",") -join ""
asdf
```

The value after the `-join` operator is the character or text you want to join with.

Alternatively you can use the more explicit .NET method [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx):

```
PS> [System.String]::Join("", "a,s,d,f".Split(","))
asdf
```

The first argument is the join character, the second the list you want to join.

Comment: Alright that is helpful, but when I use $((Get-ADRootDSE).defaultNamingContext).Split(",DC=") -join "" I get contosocom as output. Any way to place a dot between those two parts?

Comment: Just do `… -join "."`, i.e. use a dot as the join character/string.

Comment: Oh, right. Figured it out the exact moment you replied. Thank you

Comment: You can simplify with the `-split` operator too: `"a,s,d,f" -split ","`.